# python requests issue 429 bad request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

Why when I call a website with curl it works, but when call with python always return 429? I tried to set a lot different user-agent, cookies...

curl call:

```
curl "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/GLW?formatted=true&crumb=8ldhetOu7RJ&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=summaryDetail&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com"
```

response: `{"quoteSummary":{"result":[{"summaryDetail":{"maxAge":1,"priceHint":{"raw":2,"fmt":"2","longFmt":"2"},"previousClose":{"raw":37.12,"fmt":"37.12"},"open":{"raw":37.19,"fmt":"37.19"},"dayLow":{"raw":37.12,"fmt":"37.12"},"dayHigh":{"raw":37.95,"fmt":"37.95"},"regularMarketPreviousClose":{"raw":37.12,"fmt":"37.12"},"regularMarketOpen":{"raw":37.19,"fmt":"37.19"},"regularMarketDayLow":{"raw":37.12,"fmt":"37.12"},"regularMarketDayHigh":{"raw":37.95,"fmt":"37.95"},"dividendRate":{"raw":0.88,"fmt":"0.88"},"dividendYield":{"raw":0.0232,"fmt":"2.32%"},"exDividendDate":{"raw":1605139200,"fmt":"2020-11-12"},"payoutRatio":{"raw":3.3077,"fmt":"330.77%"},"fiveYearAvgDividendYield":{"raw":2.43,"fmt":"2.43"},"beta":{"raw":1.173753,"fmt":"1.17"},"trailingPE":{"raw":148.82353,"fmt":"148.82"},"forwardPE":{"raw":20.294119,"fmt":"20.29"},"volume":{"raw":3372416,"fmt":"3.37M","longFmt":"3,372,416"},"regularMarketVolume":{"raw":3372416,"fmt":"3.37M","longFmt":"3,372,416"},"averageVolume":{"raw":4245485,"fmt":"4.25M","longFmt":"4,245,485"},"averageVolume10days":{"raw":3351485,"fmt":"3.35M","longFmt":"3,351,485"},"averageDailyVolume10Day":{"raw":3351485,"fmt":"3.35M","longFmt":"3,351,485"},"bid":{"raw":37.88,"fmt":"37.88"},"ask":{"raw":37.89,"fmt":"37.89"},"bidSize":{"raw":1100,"fmt":"1.1k","longFmt":"1,100"},"askSize":{"raw":800,"fmt":"800","longFmt":"800"},"marketCap":{"raw":28994179072,"fmt":"28.99B","longFmt":"28,994,179,072"},"yield":{},"ytdReturn":{},"totalAssets":{},"expireDate":{},"strikePrice":{},"openInterest":{},"fiftyTwoWeekLow":{"raw":17.44,"fmt":"17.44"},"fiftyTwoWeekHigh":{"raw":37.95,"fmt":"37.95"},"priceToSalesTrailing12Months":{"raw":2.6921244,"fmt":"2.69"},"fiftyDayAverage":{"raw":35.406857,"fmt":"35.41"},"twoHundredDayAverage":{"raw":31.052786,"fmt":"31.05"},"trailingAnnualDividendRate":{"raw":0.86,"fmt":"0.86"},"trailingAnnualDividendYield":{"raw":0.023168104,"fmt":"2.32%"},"navPrice":{},"currency":"USD","fromCurrency":null,"toCurrency":null,"lastMarket":null,"volume24Hr":{},"volumeAllCurrencies":{},"circulatingSupply":{},"algorithm":null,"maxSupply":{},"startDate":{},"tradeable":false}}],"error":null}}`

with python:

```
import requests
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'}
result = requests.get('https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/GLW?formatted=true&crumb=8ldhetOu7RJ&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=summaryDetail&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com', headers=headers)
print result.content
```

response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 35, in <module>
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, jsondataasbytes)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

Comment: Could you just be hitting a rate limit on that URL? Or do you think there is another cause?

Comment: It is working fine for me using python requests, probably you were blocked by the site as the error mentioned.

Comment: Paisanco: another cause, because also on VPN the request doesn't work
@AvihayTsayeg it's strange because on browser and curl still work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, ok, solved by passing get parameters via params:

```
import requests
payload = {"modules": "summaryDetail"}
response = requests.get("https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/GLW", params=payload)
print(response.json())
```